# Closing NamedTemporaryFile inside context manager keeps file open

Tags: python

Today I encountered a problem that can be simplified to following (to me) harmless looking code (and it does in fact work on my mac!)

```
import tempfile
import subprocess
import os

with tempfile.NamedTemporaryFile() as tmp_file:
    with open(tmp_file.name, 'w') as writer:
        print("#!/bin/sh", file=writer)
        print("echo hi", file=writer)
    os.chmod(tmp_file.name, 0o511)
    subprocess.run([tmp_file.name], stdout=subprocess.PIPE, stderr=subprocess.PIPE)
```

On a linux machine, I however get following error: `[Errno 26] Text file busy: '/tmp/tmp1y99vl6k'`, suggesting, that the file handle opened by the writer has in fact not been closed when the subprocess is called.

Is this expected python behaviour? Is there a way to force closing the file within the `NamedTemporaryFile` context, or do I have shift to using a `TemporaryDirectory` for this?

---

Some clues I found:

> Whether the name can be used to open the file a second time, while the named temporary file is still open, varies across platforms (it can be so used on Unix; it cannot on Windows)
> https://docs.python.org/3/library/tempfile.html#tempfile.NamedTemporaryFile

Comment: You have *two* open file objects here, both including `w` in their mode.  The fact that both reference the same file on disk is irrelevant; as long as either one is open, the file is open.  Why are you reopening `tmp_file`, anyway?  Anything you can do with the reopened version can just as easily be done with the original.

Comment: I think the author of the code expected that .close() will close all file handles, while the file is not yet cleaned up, so it can be executed. This seems to be true on some operating systems, but not all.